# How to I remove the text inside a Text Area after submit React JS

Tags: reactjs, forms

I can not delete the text inside a text area after submission

I have tried setState() but it does not remove the text it only removes the value

```
   handleSubmit(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        // const data = {
        //   email:this.state.email,
        //   subject:this.state.subject,
        //   body:this.state.body,
        // }
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/nodemailer';
         axios.post( url, this.state)
        .then((res)=> {
          console.log(res);
          this.setState({email:'',subject:'',body:''});
        })
        .catch(err => {console.log('not sent'+err)});          




  `
   <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field col s12">
            <i className="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
              <textarea id={this.props.name} className="materialize-textarea" name={this.props.name} value={this.props.body} onChange={this.props.onChange} placeholder={this.props.body} ></textarea>
              <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.title}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
`
```

The expected result was to see the field with empty value after submit but the result I got was text area was still had the text but the value was empty

Comment: It seems like the `<textarea>` is not a controlled component. Can you post your jsx?

Comment: sure 
    render(){
        return(
            
            <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field col s12">
            <i className="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
              <textarea id={this.props.name} className="materialize-textarea" name={this.props.name} value={this.props.body} onChange={this.props.onChange} placeholder={this.props.body} ></textarea>
              <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.title}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

Comment: Got the problem

Comment: Problem or Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you submit, you change the state `this.setState({email:'',subject:'',body:''});`

however, the textarea doesn't have `value= this.state.body` instead it has `value={this.props.body}`

so try this :

```
<div className="row">
   <div className="input-field col s12">
        <i className="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
         <textarea id={this.props.name} className="materialize-textarea" name={this.props.name} value={this.state.bodyState} onChange={this.props.onChange}      placeholder={this.state.bodyState} ></textarea>
         <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.title}</label>
      </div>
  </div>




this.setState({bodyState = this.props.value)};

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/nodemailer';
         axios.post( url, this.state)
        .then((res)=> {
          console.log(res);
          this.setState({bodyState :''});
        })
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `onChange` function on textarea, but you did not set the text, so your component is not controlled by react. You should do something like this:

```
<textarea 
  id={this.props.name} 
  className="materialize-textarea" 
  name={this.props.name} 
  value={this.props.body} 
  onChange={this.props.onChange} 
  placeholder={this.props.body} 
>
  {this.props.body}
</textarea>
```

This way when you `setState()` and reset `this.props.body` value, the `textarea` will be empty